# Render a HTML page from a POST to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-post

I'm having issues trying to return a rendered page from an api.

I'm trying to send data from the first app via a post to the second. The second app should receive the data and then render the first page of the second app.

I have it sending and receiving the data, but i can't get the page to render.

The POST from service one:

```
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');


exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/referral-service',
    body: {
      some: 'payload'
  },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};

rp(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log(parsedBody);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('err')    
    });
};
```

The api in service 2:

```
module.exports = function(router) {

  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

      router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('welcome');
      });

    router.post('/referral-service', bodyParser.json(), function(req, 
    res, next) {

        res.render('welcome');
    });

};
```

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: @AlexanderLallier - No errors, I get the returned HTML displayed in terminal from the console.log in the resolved promise.

Comment: You are't actually returning anything in the response from API 1 so API 2 is left waiting for the reply.

Comment: @JustinPearce - could you explain in a little more detail? I'm a novice so apologies.

Comment: @fatspanner I misspoke. You are trying to get the 'welcome' so show on API 2 when API 1 makes a post to API 2, correct?

Comment: @JustinPearce, I'm trying to make two services into a seamless journey for the user. Service one ends by posting data to router.post('/referral-service') in the second service. The second service should render it's welcome page. I plan to add the received data to a session.